# using for in loop with sql output

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, if-statement

I have a roles.txt file that contains

```
admin
user
```

SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM SENTRY_ROLE WHERE ROLE_NAME produces:

```
admin
```

Im trying to echo all the roles from roles.txt that are not in the sql_output (user in this example). This is what i have so far:

```
for filename in roles.txt
do
sql_output=$(mysql -N -e "SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM SENTRY_ROLE WHERE ROLE_NAME = '$filename';") 


if [ -z "$sql_output" ]
then
  echo "sql_output is empty" #this is where i want to echo all the roles that are not in the output of sql_output AKA "user"
else
  echo "\$sql_output is in sql_output"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you iterate over the lines of a file. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

I would do this, with a single mysql call:

```
# Iassume this does not produce any extraneous output,
# just a list of role names, one per line
sql_output=$( mysql -N -e "SELECT distinct ROLE_NAME FROM SENTRY_ROLE" ) 

missing_roles=$( comm -23 roles.txt <(echo "$sql_output") )
```

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/comm.1.html

Comment: Trying to make this work, its not liking echo $sql_output.  syntax error near unexpected token `('. ` comm -23 test.txt <(echo "$sql_output") )'

Comment: That is bash [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) syntax: use `#!/bin/bash` or if you need to use /bin/sh, then redirect the mysql output to a file and use that filename in place of the `<(echo ...)`

Comment: the reason i was using if then is that if there are missing roles i wanted to create them with sql command

Comment: If you have an index on that table, you might want to consider using `INSERT IGNORE` and then you don't need to do the query and filtering at all.